# How to put the child behind the parent with z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have this problem as described in the title, can't put the `child_child` behind all other parents?

is this possible?  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey8fk394/)

Comment: because its a nested child. only direct child can be z-indexed. check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6s8g8mn/)

Comment: what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain and how should the html structure be changed like ?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: it works if you give your class .big position: absolute instead of fixed.

Comment: One thing you learn when you become a parent, is that children come first, no matter what "index" they came in  ;)    (sorry, i had to!)

Answer (score 1):

Set `z-index` only for last child [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey8fk394/10/) and remove floating, change fixed to relative positioning:

CSS:

```
.big {
    position: relative;
    background-color:red;
    width:420px;
    height:100px;
}
.small {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
}
.child_child {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:10px;
    width:400px;
    height:180px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Checked in main browsers - OK.
[image]

Comment: it is not behind the red container. remove bg color from .small and have a look.

Comment: I see it is different in diferrent browsers, will try to fix. (Firefox is good)

Answer (score 0):

- Change `.big`'s position to `absolute`.
- Add `z-index: -1;` to `ul`

```css
.big {
  background-color: red;
  width: 420px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.small {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
ul {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
.child_child {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <nav class="small">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="child_child"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the z-index of the wrapper (big) first:

like this:

```
.big{
    background-color:red;
    width:400px; height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
}
.small{
    float:left; position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    top:10px;
    width:400px; height:150px;
    z-index:initial;
}
.child_child{
    float:left; position:absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:10px;
    width:400px; height:180px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PauloSegundo/v8Ljo77v/

Comment: Omg, why negative? Negatives are only used when the answer is off topic. Tested in chrome and worked for me. Look the fiddle

Comment: i think you said  `need to set z-index of the wrapper (big) first`  remove the z-index from wrapper (big) have no changes from above fiddle,

Comment: You are right, the only thing needed was set only the child_child z-index. Just don't know why the down votes :/

Comment: I gave a downvote because your answer is false. the yellow element should be behind all other parents. remove background color from .small in your example and have a look at it in chrome. posting 100% false answers and providing a js fiddle to show they are false does not make them any better.