# z-index wont work with positions set

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. One is a bar with background transparency - this contains a menu. The other contains an image. I want the image to be behind the first div. I can't get the z-index to do this:

```
<div id="headerwrapper">
    <div class="mastheadimage"><img src="....." /></div>
    ...more code
</div>

css
#headerwrapper {
position:relative;
z-index:10;
background-color:rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.3);
}

.mastheadimage {
position:absolute;
z-index:-1; 
}
```

I have tried various different numbers for the -1

Comment: try having them as siblings rather then a parent/child, then position them

Comment: You can also make the image transparent a bit, the result should be similar.

Comment: thanks guys - sorted! I love Stackoverflow

Comment: You can also take a look at this answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236167/how-to-put-the-child-behind-the-parent-with-z-index/28236288#28236288).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `mastheadimage` is nested within `headerwrapper`.

You need to split them up to achieve what you are looking for, perhaps wrapping the two in an overall parent.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="headerwrapper">...more code</div>
    <div class="mastheadimage"><img src="....." /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
```